# SSIS - Best process for PDF to TIF conversion

Tags: pdf, ssis, tiff

I have an SSIS package that currently delivers specific PDF/TIF files from one server to another server to be picked up via FTP by several different clients based on a query.  We now have a new requirement that all files that are delivered to the clients must be in TIF format.

Ideally, I would like to add a step in the package that would convert the files if they are PDF.

Is there a best practice for doing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a requirement to deliver a TIFF file instead of PDF then keeping a task (I would prefer script task) to convert that for you. With C# you can find various open source or paid libraries which can do easily for you; for example:

- [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)
- [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)
- [GhostScriptAPI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API)

Do not try to reinvent the wheel, until you have a solid reason to defend it.